# Set Metadata Dynamically Without Duplicate Requests - NextJS 13

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

Consider the following server side component that's part of some page (page.js) in the app directory, representing a person:

```
export default async function Person({ params }) {
    const person = await getPerson(params.id);
    
    return (
        <h1> {person.name} </h1>
        <p> {person.bio} </p>
    )
}
```

Obviously, the intent here is to dynamically render new pages, with the idea being that the URL looks something like `/person/{id}`, where ID is the unique ID of each person.

The issue I'm running into is that I need to set metadata for the page. For example, I want the title to be `person.name`, and the description to be `person.description`. From what I'm reading, the only way to do that in NextJS 13 with the app directory is to use `generateMetadata`, which would look something like this:

```
export async function generateMetadata({ params }) {
    const person = await getPerson(params.id);

    return {
        title: person.name,
        description: person.description
    }
}
```

I'm sure you can see the issue now: I need to make the exact same request (`getPerson`) twice in the same page. From what I've seen, there isn't a way to pass data between `generateMetadata` and the page component.

The `<Head>` component from `next/head` seems like the ideal solution, but it doesn't appear to work in the app directory with NextJS 13.

Am I missing something really obvious here? Or is this an absolutely massive oversight by Next's devs?

Answer (score 13):

If the function you're calling is internally calling fetch it is automatically deduplicated by Next.js as can be read in the official documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching#automatic-fetch-request-deduping).

---

Should you be directly calling a database or using a fetch alternative (like axios) as explained you can use Reacts new `cache()` function to deduplicate calls to logic that does not automatically get deduped by Next.js. More can be found in the official documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching#automatic-fetch-request-deduping)

```
import { cache } from 'react'
 
export const getPerson = cache(async () => {
   // your logic ...
});
```

Although the `getPerson()` function is called twice, inside the page and metadata generator, only one call will be made. This is because the function is wrapped in `cache()`, so the second request can reuse the result from the first request.

Comment: interesting, thanks so much. I should’ve specified, but I am using `fetch` underneath `getPerson`

Comment: looks like I spoke too soon - when testing with my backend, Next is in fact making duplicate requests when using `fetch` underneath `getPerson` (which turns into a single request when `generateMetadata` is removed). Haven't tested it in production, so it may just be an issue in the development server. Going to give `cache` a try...

Comment: @TwistedTea Things work fine in production https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/53035#issuecomment-1646559023

Comment: @RishabSharma Ha, good find, thanks. Next13's dev environment is a buggy disaster

Comment: @TwistedTea I suspect this is by design, otherwise using hot reload you might encounter stale data etc. The same way static routes are dynamic on development.

Answer (score 0):

In NextJS data requests are cached unless you opt out according to official doc on the [data cache](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#data-cache)

> React extends the fetch API to automatically memoize requests that have the same URL and options. This means you can call a fetch function for the same data in multiple places in a React component tree while only executing it once.

Comment: OP is not using fetch, asking for a server side call.

Comment: This is about server side call.

Comment: Oh, I meant server action. Still not a valid reply though. Only fetch api's will get memoized automatically, OP is not using fetch.